# Will a MYSQL Insert statement ever return something not a 1?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to think of some error scenarios, and let's say we have a simple statement like:

```
INSERT INTO CAT_TABLE (NAME, BREED, AGE) VALUES ("Henry", "Siamese", 2)
```

The primary key here is the name of the cat. Under most, if not all circumstances this should return a 1. In terms of the JDBC API, is there a time it can return something that isn't a 1? I know if there is an issue with the values itself, it would just throw a SQL exception but when will it throw a 0 or some numerical value not a 1?

UPDATE:

Java code for using this statement would be something like:

```
Connection connection = getConnection(...);
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
int result = ps.executeUpdate();
connection.commit();
return result;
```

Comment: Out of interest, how would you handle a 2 year old pursian cat also called Henry?

Comment: What do you mean by *this should return a 1*? SQL statements are not functions that return values.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Comment: @forpas I added an update

Comment: @Stu I would either throw an exception with the sql error that comes back or use a select and if it exists, throw an exception

Comment: @stackerstack Okay :-) I was more hinting at the unique constraint on `name` being rather unusual - I don't know your data or use-case though so only an observation.

Comment: @Stu Oh yes I totally agree with you about cat names being unique LOL. This was something I just made up on the fly for some reason I just wanted to choose a constraint on cat names. Look's like we ban all cats named Henry in this world from our shop :p

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean the *rows affected* of the INSERT statement. An INSERT statement itself has no result. The rows affected for an INSERT statement would be the number of rows inserted.

You can INSERT from a SELECT result set:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM ...
```

That SELECT could have a result of zero rows, or one row, or many rows.

It might also not be the number of rows of the SELECT result, if you use INSERT IGNORE and some of the rows succeed while other rows are ignored because of errors.

You can also make an INSERT statement that inserts multiple rows without a SELECT statement:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3) 
VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9), ...
```

That could also report rows affected more than 1.

Comment: If we stick to only 1 single insert, would it ever return anything that's not a 1, and not an exception?

Comment: @stackerstack No

Comment: Exceptions are a client language thing. If it fails to insert a row, then rows affected will be zero.

Comment: @BillKarwin The question is asked in the context of the JDBC API.

Comment: @BillKarwin Exactly what Mark said!

Comment: If you only count scenarios that would report 1 row affected, then of course they will only return 1! :-)